# Mule 3 and Maven: "filterAppDirectory" config param not working

Tags: maven, mule

I have a Mule 3.3 project that uses Maven.  I want the Mule Maven plugin to apply filtering to my Mule config file (located at: "src/main/app/mule-config.xml")

I set the "filterAppDirectory" config parameter to "true" like it says in the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/maven-mule-plugin), but that doesn't work.  It just copies the config file into the project ZIP file without filtering it.

Here is my POM:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <filters>
      <filter>src/main/filters/filter.properties</filter>
    </filters>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
          <filterAppDirectory>true</filterAppDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Opened an issue on the maven-mule-plugin project page:

https://github.com/mulesoft/maven-mule-plugin/issues/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.7 of the plugin does not support the `<filterAppDirectory>` configuration parameter.  Support was added in version 1.8.

See: https://github.com/mulesoft/maven-mule-plugin/issues/10